# Graph API: event's RSVP check

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm currently trying to get an idea of getting Facebook's RSVP for an event, but really stuck on that part:

as I see now, to get user's RSVP I have to make three requests with the following logic:

```
 request eventID/attending/userID -> 

 if "data" array count == 0 -> 

 request eventID/maybe/userID -> 

 if "data" array count == 0 -> 

 request eventID/declined/userID

 else -> means user didn't make any choice previously.
```

So here it looks like I have to make 3 requests to facebook's graph api to get users's RSVP for a single event.

The question is if there is any way to get an RSVP status for an event doing a single request?

I'm using the latest Facebook SDK and the latest graph api.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The closest solution to what you're looking for is probably to query `/event_id/?fields=attending,maybe,declined`. This will return all users who've responded to the event. There isn't a way to filter this to a single user ID though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure if it helps. I got an event ID, got a userID, got this user's rsvp token and want to get his RSVP status for an eventID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the best solution here so far is:

- one request to /eventID/attending/userID
- one request to /eventID/maybe/userID
- one request to /eventID/declined/userID (if needed to  know if the event invitation was declined)

Call to eventID/attending(maybe/declined)/userID lets us filter rsvp to single user, so we avoid downloading and processing a large amount of data here.

After call you have two options:

1. If result is true, you get the following response:

`{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Oleskii Poplavlen",
      "id": "10204715567996406",
      "rsvp_status": "attending"
    }
]}`

2. If result is false, you get the following response:

`{
  "data": []
 }`

So while you still have to make multiple requests to get user's RSVP to event, you can avoid downloading loads of other users's rsvps.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I can get you started to do it in 2 calls:

```
FB.api('/'+ event_id + '?fields=id,attending{rsvp_status},maybe{rsvp_status}', function(event_response){

    // here you should make a call to check if the user has the event and if so get the rsvp_status

    FB.api('/'+ user_id + '/events?fields=id,rsvp_status', function(user_response){

       // check if user has event, then log the rsvp_status

       if(user_response.id == event_response.id) {
          console.log(user_response.rsvp_status);
       } else {
          console.log("user is not going");
     });
});
```

I have not tested this but I've been playing around with this API for quite a while now. This could be an answer to do it in 2 calls, not in 1 unfortunatly.

The first call doesn't need the 'attending' and 'maybe' fields but it's usefull to test with.